# Populating JTable from array

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Been looking around but couldn't find anything that explain how to do something like this:

```
Object rowData[] = { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "Row1-Column3" };

Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three" };
```

I already made a table with the editor, name: "jTable1".

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the arrays and the functions to populate the table. Eg: `jTable1.addColumn(columnNames);` gives an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this will help you:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
model.addRow(rowData);
jTable1.setModel(model);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a two-dimensional array for the row data. Try this:

```
Object rowData[][] = {{ "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "Row1-Column3" }};
Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three" };
JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
```