# How i can print wmi query in jList or jTable?

Tags: java, jtable, jlist, wmic

I have this code but i don't know to display in jList or jTable

This code i have still println

```
try {
  Process sysProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "wmic", "product", "get", "name",",","version" });
  BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sysProcess.getInputStream()));

  Scanner sc = new Scanner(sysProcess.getInputStream());
  String line = sc.nextLine();

  while((line=streamReader.readLine())!=null) {                
    System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried googling it ?

Comment: sure, and i try to code with my experience, but it didn't work. Is exec(new String[]) is affect the code in jList?

Comment: You should post the code you have tried for that problem here. Others can give u a direction then only

Comment: i just replace System.out.println(line);
with model.addElement(line);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123811/populating-jtable-from-array have you tried this ?

Comment: A complete example is seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20603012/230513).

Comment: thank you Mr trashgod its working :)